# Почему не находится файл?

Tags: java, android

Метод следующий:

```
private boolean file_exist(String path, String name_file){
    String fs = System.getProperty("file.separator");
    File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ fs + path + fs, name_file);
    return file.exists() && file.isFile();
}
```

Применяю:

```
if (file_exist("dbs","default_base")) not_found = false;
  else not_found = true;
```

Файл существует и в нем есть запись (проверял), но прога говорит, что "not_found = true" .
Выводил в лог:

```
Log.d("MyLog",String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ fs + path + fs + name_file);
```

/data/data/com.ex.base/files/dbs/default_base

Не могу понять почему не находит?

UPD:
Обнаружил следующее:

Если пишу так:

```
String nf = "default.dbs";
File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ "/" + NAME_PATH_DB + "/" + nf);
if (file.exists()) fe = true; else fe = false;
```

результат false

Если так:

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ "/" + NAME_PATH_DB + "/" + "default.dbs");
if (file.exists()) fe = true; else fe = false;
```

результат true

Comment: а доступ к файлу имеется? И попробуйте данную строку куда-то выводить и посмотреть что с ней не так. И не понятно что за контекст и что за path, чем они разнятся

Comment: и да если вы пишете под андроид, вам навряд нужен сепаратор, в юникс системах он одинаков, а во вторых может встретится символ "\", тогда вы должы будете сделать так "\\"

Comment: У файла точно именно такое имя, и без расширения? Может, например, default_base.txt? Или default_base.sqlite?

Comment: У файла точно такое имя, без расширения.

Comment: @kaaa вы попробывали что я написал?

Comment: Файл был записан программно из того же приложения?

Comment: Да, файл и каталог были записаны программно из этого приложения. Выводить строку я пробовал, но с ней все в порядке. Контекст нужен чтобы определить рабочий каталог проекта, path - это дополнительный каталог ("dbs") в каталоге проекта. Про сепаратор я знаю, просто пробовал разные варианты, но что с ним, что без него - одинаковый результат.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в вашей функции file_exist заменить запятую после `fs` на `+`:

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ fs + path + fs + name_file);
```

Comment: Уже пробовал. Не помогло.

Comment: `File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir()) + fs + path);
File[] files = folder.listFiles();` - содержит ли полученный массив files ваш файл?

Comment: Да, содержит. Вот лог: /data/data/com.ex.base/files/dbs/default_base

Comment: А если убрать проверку `&& file.isFile()`, что возвращает функция?

Comment: То же самое - false. Я уже думал искать нужный файл в списке files[], т.к. он там есть, но при попытке открыть этот файл, чтобы прочитать от туда содержимое получил :  Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dbs/default_base : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Внес дополнительную информацию, может это как-то прояснит.