# Не находится файл. Почему?

Tags: java, android

Вопрос уточняющий предыдущий [Почему не находится файл?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/673106/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb)

Если пишу так:

```
String nf = "default.dbs";
File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ "/" + NAME_PATH_DB + "/" + nf);
fe = file.exists();
```

результат false

Если так:

```
File file = new File(String.valueOf(context.getFilesDir())+ "/" + NAME_PATH_DB + "/" + "default.dbs");
fe = file.exists();
```

результат true

Почему?

UPD:

```
file: /data/data/com.example.ka_ba.sotis/files/dbs/default.dbs
fe: false
file: /data/data/com.example.ka_ba.sotis/files/dbs/default.dbs
fe: true
```

Comment: Куски кода идентичны в смысле выполнения. Ошибка где-то в другом месте. На всякий случай, конечно, покажите что в логи выведется коли туда аргумент конструктора файла вывести

Comment: И сократите `if (file.exists()) fe = true; else fe = false;` до `fe = file.exists();`

Comment: Добавил UPD к вопросу. Вывел логи. Абсолютно одинаково, но результат разный.

Comment: Ну, значит магия какая-то. Используйте просто тот вариант который работает

Comment: Так в том то и дело, что переменная nf должна принимать разные значения. Мистика, хоть бубен доставай.

Comment: А если не передавать кучу строк в конструктор, а сначала сформировать путь в переменной к-л, а потом оную в конструктор передать? Также проверьте, что у вас неразрывных невидимых пробелом нет в частях пути. Т.е. сделайте `String nf = "default.dbs".trim();`

Comment: Ну и проверьте через `equals` что у вас ваши строки таки совпадают

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромаднейшее! trim решил проблему! Проверил на совпадение - не равны, применил trim и стали равны. А на экране выглядели равными. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста) Написал в ответ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда очевидно равные строки не равны, то проблема может быть в невидимых символах. Например неразрывных пробелах с нулевой шириной, переносах строк etc. Для очистки строк от этих символов надо использовать метод `String#trim()`. Т.е. как-то так:

```
String someStringThatMightHaveInvisibleSymbolsSuchAsNonBreakingSpace = " ssdfsd ";
someStringThatMightHaveInvisibleSymbolsSuchAsNonBreakingSpace  = 
    someStringThatMightHaveInvisibleSymbolsSuchAsNonBreakingSpace.trim();
```

Теперь у строки обрезаны первый и последний пробелы